# Basic Authentication with Flash

Tags: flash, http, authentication, rest

This is *** unbelievable! Flash programmers are familiar with the example:

```
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://yoursite.com/yourservice.ext");
req.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
req.data = new URLVariables("name=John+Doe");

var encoder:Base64Encoder = new Base64Encoder();        
encoder.encode("yourusername:yourpassword");

var credsHeader:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encoder.toString());
req.requestHeaders.push(credsHeader);

var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.load(req);
```

OK... great... that realy works. As you can see I manually add a header Authorization for Basic HTTP authentication. BUT... if I change request metod from POST to GET, the header is not generated.

Is there anyone that knows a solution?
1000x thx!

Comment: I found this: http://www.abdulqabiz.com/blog/archives/2006/03/03/http-authentication-for-httpget-requests-using-actionscript-3/

Answer (score 5):

I'm surprised you've even been able to get it to work with a `POST` request. In December 2007, Flash Player was updated to explicitly disallow the `Authorization header`. I guess it's possible that they've since re-allowed it. But I'd be surprised by that. **Edit**: as per @derFunk’s comment, it turns out that in fact the header was subsequently re-allowed, although when sending it to a different domain it has to be explicitly permitted in `crossdomain.xml`.

Beyond specific issues with the `Authorization` header, I'm pretty sure that Flash Player will only send custom request headers with a `POST` request. I'm sorry I don't have a link for that, but at my firm we use Flash Player extensively to work with Restful web services, and we've had to implement all kinds of workarounds to make things work.

Bottom line, Flash Player has **awful** support for HTTP. In fact, our set of workaround is activated by sending the request header `X-Crippled-Client: true`, which tells our services to  interpret requests, and send responses, in mangled ways. It's a real pain in the butt.

Sorry I can't be more helpful… good luck!

Comment: More details on the Authorization Header can be found here: http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/authorization-header-request-flash-player.html : "Starting with Adobe Flash Player 9.0.115.0 the Authorization header was added to the blacklist of HTTP headers and, only in this version, was blocked by Flash Player. For Flash Player versions later than 9.0.115.0, the Authorization header is notblocked, but the destination domainrequires a crossdomain.xml file to specify that the Authorization header is allowed, if it is different from the domain hosting the SWF file."

Answer (score 3):

@Flax: yup, I couldn't agree more on flash security with HTTP headers. But there is one more way to do this, but that requires bit of work. Try using Socket instead of URLLoader, because Socket don't have those kind of restrictions. So for HTTP request open a socket to port 80 of the server (http://yoursite.com/). As soon as it is connected to server, send all your http request headers. Then on SocketDataEvent, parse the data and read (or discard) the response headers, and proceed with the data.

Comment: Yea... i did this... but now I have problem with crossdomain security :). Sockets will do the trick for non HTTP servers like chat server where you can manualy satisfy flash with crossdomain (example: http://coderslike.us/2009/01/23/flash-socket-code-and-crossdomain-policy-serving/).

Comment: here you can use Security.loadPolicyFile("http://www.yoursite.com/crossdomain.xml"); before connecting on the Socket.

Answer (score 2):

So this is super old but it came up while I was searching for a way to use Parse.com with the Flash Player.

I'm baffled that this actually works, but to get Flash to send headers in a GET command, just set it as a POST, but run an override.

```
req.requestHeaders.push(new URLRequestHeader("X-HTTP-Method-Override", URLRequestMethod.GET));
```

I tried it thinking that it was crazy and couldn't possibly work, but it does!

Answer (score 0):

You can send headers by GET methods also, except if you test it on standalone Flash Player Debugger(don't test on simple) **v.11.4.402.265**. If you open your local swf in browser it works fine too.